# Java - sending POST

Tags: java, eclipse, post, get

I'm trying to make java make a new addition to a url shortener, here's what I have:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://shmkane.com/index.php?";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "url=testingThis";

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

I'd like for it to put something in "form1" and then "submit"
[here's the site](http://shmkane.com)

I'm very new to this so any help would be great, possible tell me what I'm doing wrong or improving/fixing the code I currently have.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: I guess it's not submitting the request

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? What's it outputting? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: When I check to see the site if any new links have been added, it doesn't show up. There are no errors. Console just shows this message: http://pastie.org/8703268

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site doesn't support post:

```
<form method="get" id="form1" action="index.php">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>
      <input class="textBox" id="url" placeholder="Paste a link to shorten it" type="text" name="url" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="textBox" placeholder="Custom alias" id="alias" maxlength="15" type="text" name="alias" value="">
    </p>
    <div class="button">
      <p>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Shorten">
      </p>
<br>
      <div class="alert-box success">
        <center>
          <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
        </center>
      </div>
      <em>May only contain letters, numbers, dashes and underscores.</em>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Notice the method is `GET`.  Change to this:

```
 String urlParameters = "url=testingThis";
 String url = "http://shmkane.com/index.php?";
 URL obj = new URL(url + urlParameters);
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

 con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

And get rid of the writing to the output stream.

Comment: Thank's, this worked, so just to clarity, does the Requested Method depend on the form type on the website? And also, how would I get the link it sends me from the site?

Comment: @shmkane yes, it does.  It has to match what the HTTP server is expecting so it can parse the parameters accordingly.  There are a number of ways that you can grab the link, but you'll need to read in the response like you're doing and then somehow parse the response using some sort of standard format. I would suggest you look for tips on parsing html.  Alternatively, look for a url that returns json or xml.